# How to treat a lens (or any other optic) as a getter and setter simultaneously?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to write a generic record updater which will allow one to easily update fields in an `existing` record, with fields in a similarly shaped `incoming` record. Here is what I have till now:

```
applyUpdater fields existing incoming =
  let getters = DL.map (^.) fields
      setters = DL.map set fields
      updaters = DL.zipWith (,) getters setters
  in DL.foldl' (\updated (getter, setter) -> setter (getter incoming) updated) existing updaters
```

And I wish to use it in the following manner:

```
applyUpdater 
  [email, notificationEnabled] -- the fields to be copied from incoming => existing (this obviously assumed that `name` and `email` lenses have already been setup
  User{name="saurabh", email="blah@blah.com", notificationEnabled=True}
  User{name="saurabh", email="foo@bar.com", notificationEnabled=False}
```

This doesn't work, probably because Haskell infers a very weird type signature for `applyUpdater` which means it it not doing what I'm expecting it to do:

```
applyUpdater :: [ASetter t1 t1 a t] -> t1 -> Getting t (ASetter t1 t1 a t) t -> t1
```

Here's a code-sample and the compile error:

```
module TryUpdater where
import Control.Lens
import GHC.Generics
import Data.List as DL

data User = User {_name::String, _email::String, _notificationEnabled::Bool} deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
makeLensesWith classUnderscoreNoPrefixFields ''User

-- applyUpdater :: [ASetter t1 t1 a t] -> t1 -> Getting t (ASetter t1 t1 a t) t -> t1
applyUpdater fields existing incoming =
  let getters = DL.map (^.) fields
      setters = DL.map set fields
      updaters = DL.zipWith (,) getters setters
  in DL.foldl' (\updated (getter, setter) -> setter (getter incoming) updated) existing updaters

testUpdater :: User -> User -> User
testUpdater existingUser incomingUser = applyUpdater [email, notificationEnabled] existingUser incomingUser
```

Compile error:

```
18  62 error           error:
 • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘[Char]’
     arising from a functional dependency between:
       constraint ‘HasNotificationEnabled User String’
         arising from a use of ‘notificationEnabled’
       instance ‘HasNotificationEnabled User Bool’
         at /Users/saurabhnanda/projects/vl-haskell/.stack-work/intero/intero54587Sfx.hs:8:1-51
 • In the expression: notificationEnabled
   In the first argument of ‘applyUpdater’, namely
     ‘[email, notificationEnabled]’
   In the expression:
     applyUpdater [email, notificationEnabled] existingUser incomingUser (intero)
18  96 error           error:
 • Couldn't match type ‘User’
                  with ‘(String -> Const String String)
                        -> ASetter User User String String
                        -> Const String (ASetter User User String String)’
   Expected type: Getting
                    String (ASetter User User String String) String
     Actual type: User
 • In the third argument of ‘applyUpdater’, namely ‘incomingUser’
   In the expression:
     applyUpdater [email, notificationEnabled] existingUser incomingUser
   In an equation for ‘testUpdater’:
       testUpdater existingUser incomingUser
         = applyUpdater
             [email, notificationEnabled] existingUser incomingUser (intero)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that `(^.)` takes the lens as its *right* argument, so what you really want is actually `getters = DL.map (flip (^.)) fields`, aka `DL.map view field`.

But the more interesting problem here: optics require higher-rank polymorphism, so GHC can only *guess* types. Always *start out* with the type signature for this reason!

Naïvely, you would probably write

```
applyUpdater :: [Lens' s a] -> s -> s -> s
```

Well, that doesn't actually work, because `Lens'` includes a `∀` quantifier so putting it in a list [would require impredicative polymorphism, which GHC isn't really capable of](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImpredicativePolymorphism). Common problem, so the lens library has two ways of getting around that:

- [`ALens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens) is just a specific instantiation of the `Functor` constraint, chosen so you retain the full generality. You need to use different combinators for applying it, however.

  ```
  applyUpdater :: [ALens' s a] -> s -> s -> s
  applyUpdater fields existing incoming =
   let getters = DL.map (flip (^#)) fields
       setters = DL.map storing fields
       updaters = DL.zipWith (,) getters setters
   in DL.foldl' (\upd (γ, σ) -> σ (γ incoming) upd) existing updaters
  ```

  Because `ALens` is strictly an instantiation of `Lens`, you can use that exactly the way you intended.
- [`ReifiedLens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedLens) keeps the original polymorphism, but wraps it in a newtype so the lenses can be stored in e.g. a list. The wrapped lens can then be used as usual, but you'll need to explicitly wrap them to pass into your function; this is probably not worth the hassle for your application. This approach is more useful when you want to re-use the stored lenses in a less direct manner. (This can also be done with `ALens`, but it requires `cloneLens` which I reckon is bad for performance.)

`applyUpdater` will now work the way I explained with `ALens'`, however it can only be used with a lists of lenses *all focusing of fields of the same type*. Putting lenses focusing on fields of *different* type in a list is quite clearly a type error. To accomplish that, you *must* wrap the lenses in some newtype to hide the type parameter – no way around it, it's simply not possible to unify the types of `email` and `notificationEnabled` to something you can stuff in one single list.

But before going through that trouble, I would strongly consider *not* storing any lenses in a list at all: basically what is just composing update-functions that all access a shared reference. Well, do that directly – “all accessing a shared reference” is, conveniently, exactly what the function monad offers you, so it's trivial to write

```
applyUpdater :: [s -> r -> s] -> s -> r -> s
applyUpdater = foldr (>=>) pure
```

To convert a lens to an individual updater-function, write

```
mkUpd :: ALens' s a -> s -> s -> s
mkUpd l exi inc = storing l (inc^#l) exi
```

to be used like

```
applyUpdater 
  [mkUpd email, mkUpd notificationEnabled]
  User{name="saurabh", email="blah@blah.com", notificationEnabled=True}
  User{name="saurabh", email="foo@bar.com", notificationEnabled=False}
```

Comment: I tried the approach you suggested with `ALens'` but I'm getting a different error now: `Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘ALens (ALens' s a) t0 a b0’
       ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
         the type signature for:
           applyUpdater :: forall s a. [ALens' s a] -> s -> s -> s
         at /Users/saurabhnanda/projects/vl-haskell/.stack-work/intero/intero54587Sfx.hs:10:17
       Expected type: [(s -> a, a -> s -> s)]
         Actual type: [(ALens (ALens' s a) t0 a b0 -> a, a -> s -> s)]`

Comment: There's another problem with your code, namely you've partially-applied `^.`, respectively `^#`, the wrong way around. Does is work with `DL.map (flip (^#)) fields`?

Comment: `applyUpdater` compiles with the `flip`, but actually using it still causes a type error. eg: `testUpdater existingUser incomingUser = applyUpdater [email, notificationEnabled] existingUser incomingUser` results in `Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘[Char]’
         arising from a functional dependency between:
           constraint ‘HasNotificationEnabled User String’
             arising from a use of ‘notificationEnabled’
           instance ‘HasNotificationEnabled User Bool’`

Comment: Uh, you want to put _lenses to different-typed fields in a single list_? It shouldn't surprise you that this doesn't work, right?

Comment: Can this be done by tuples instead?  Something like `applyUpdater2` `applyUpdater3`, `applyUpdater4`, etc?

Comment: It seems to be working with tuples. Would you know how to make this code shorter? `applyUpdater2 (f1, f2) existing incoming = (storing f2 (incoming ^# f2)) $ (storing f1 (incoming ^# f1) existing)`

Comment: Well... use shorter variable names? But really, I don't think it's sensible to wrap these things in a fixed-length _tuple_. Do use a list, but store only the concrete-updater form that doesn't mention the updated-element-type anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Based off @leftaroundabout 's answer, there's an approach based on tuples as well:

```
applyUpdater2 (f1, f2) existing incoming = (storing f2 (incoming ^# f2)) $ (storing f1 (incoming ^# f1) existing)
applyUpdater3 (f1, f2, f3) existing incoming = (storing f3 (incoming ^# f3)) $ (applyUpdater2 (f1, f2) existing incoming)
applyUpdater4 (f1, f2, f3, f4) existing incoming = (storing f4 (incoming ^# f4)) $ (applyUpdater3 (f1, f2, f3) existing incoming)
-- and so on
```

Which can be used in the following manner:

```
testUpdater :: User -> User -> User
testUpdater existingUser incomingUser = applyUpdater2 (email, notificationEnabled) existingUser incomingUser
```

Setting up `applyUpdaterN` till, say 32-tuples, should be easy enough. After that, it all boils down to personal preference and actual use-cases. You *may* prefer not having to wrap your updaters with `mkUpd` at every call site. On the other hand, if you want to generate the `updaters` list dynamically, then working with lists is easier than working with tuples.