# How to apply the same lens on two different records? (or, record field-names as first-class values?)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Consider the following records and their lenses:

```
data Bar = Bar {barField1 :: Int, barField2 :: String}
makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''Bar

data BarError = BarError {barerrField1 :: [String], barerrField2 :: [String]}
makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''BarError
```

Now, both of them have access to the lenses `field1` & `field2` by virtue of implementing the `HasField1` and `HasField2` type-classes. However, I am unable to get the following piece of code to compile:

```
-- Most-general type-signature inferred by the compiler, if I remove the
-- KindSignatures from `record` & `errRecord` below:
--
-- validateLength :: (IsString a) => (Int, Int) -> ALens t t [a] [a] -> t -> t -> t
-- 
validateLength (mn, mx) l (record :: Bar)  (errRecord :: BarErr) =
  let len = length (record ^# l)
  in if ((len<mn) || (len>mx))
  then errRecord & l #%~ (\x -> ("incorrect length"):x)
  else errRecord

-- Usage scenario:
--
-- let x = Bar 10 "hello there"
--     xErr = BarError [] []
-- in validateLength (3, 10) field2 x xErr
```

Error message:

```
/Users/saurabhnanda/projects/vl-haskell/src/TryLens.hs:18:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘BarError’ with ‘Bar’
      Expected type: BarError -> BarError
        Actual type: Bar -> BarError
    • In the second argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘l #%~ (\ x -> ("incorrect length") : x)’
      In the expression:
        errRecord & l #%~ (\ x -> ("incorrect length") : x)
      In the expression:
        if ((len < mn) || (len > mx)) then
            errRecord & l #%~ (\ x -> ("incorrect length") : x)
        else
            errRecord
```

**Note:** Instead of using `^.` and `%~` I'm using `^#` and `#%~` because I'd like to [treat the lens (`l`) as a getter & setter simultaneously.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618101/how-to-treat-a-lens-or-any-other-optic-as-a-getter-and-setter-simultaneously)

**Edit:** A simpler snippet to demonstrate the problem is:

```
-- intended type signature:
-- funkyLensAccess :: l -> r1 -> r2 -> (t1, t2)
--
-- type signature inferred by the compiler
-- funkyLensAccess :: Getting t s t -> s -> s -> (t, t)
--
funkyLensAccess l rec1 rec2 = (rec1 ^. l, rec2 ^. l)
```

Comment: Type sig please...

Comment: I'm not sure of the correct type-signature and am letting the compiler infer the type-signature. I'll put the inferred type-signature in the question, and that will make it obvious why it's not type-checking. In that case please consider the intent of the question - I'm trying to figure out HOW to write this piece of code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Done!

Comment: That signature can't match, it has too few arguments. (Also, as I have often said, I find it backwards to write some sort of implementation and then let the compiler infer its signature... you're not really interested in the implementation (and anyway you know it isn't quite right), what you know is _how you want to use this_, and that's how you should decide what the signature is supposed to be. Only _after_ you've settled on the signature, you should start to write any implementation code.)

Comment: If you give your function a type signature (as a first approximation, you could use `(Int, Int) -> t -> Bar -> BarError -> BarError` since you don't know the required type of the Lens), and replace both occurrences of `l` with a typed hole, the 1st occurrence has type `ALens Bar t0 [a0] b0` (for some `t0,a0,b0`) and the 2nd `ALens BarError BarError [[Char]] [[Char]]`. Do you see how these types cannot possible unify? Maybe you want e.g. `forall a . ALens a a [String] [String]`, but this doesn't allow you to pass `field1` or `field2` to the function...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree with your approach in general. However, in the case of lenses, I just get a mind-block and I'm unable to even express my intent in terms of a type-signature first.

Comment: ...Furthermore, based on the use case, this approach isn't really sensible.  Just because `(x :: Bar) ^. field1` and `(x :: BarError) ^. field1` both typecheck, doesn't mean there is a single term which corresponds to a lens which can be used on both `Bar` and `BarError` to manipulate the first field. In these two pieces of code, the two `field1`s are entirely different terms; if you pass `field1` as a parameter, you pick a specific instantiation, and neither instantiation can possibly apply to the other type.

Comment: @user2407038 is there any other lens-hackery that can enable me to do what I want? Conceptually, what I"m trying to do is to use a field-name as a first-class value -- once as a getter and once as a setter on two DIFFERENT records.

Comment: "is there any other lens-hackery that can enable me to do what I want?" -for the reasons I've stated, it isn't reasonable to expect lenses to do this - this is not what a 'lens' is. A lens operates on a value of *a particular type* and the substructure it operates on must have *a particular type* (this is true of all optics, except perhaps the most exotic ones I'm not aware of). Note this has nothing to do with wanting to use a lens as both a getter and setter. Your issue is wanting to use a lens at multiple different types, but there is no type of which both desired uses are instantiations.

Answer (score 3):

So essentially your problem has nothing to do with lenses, but with (accessor-) functions that can operate on different types, for each giving a different-typed result.

That immediately means trouble: if the accessed-field type is supposed to depend on the containing-struct type, this is a [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Haskell is not a dependently-typed language. It's the kind of task you can easily do in e.g. Python by calling a field *by name* (in form of a string) and then operating on the field via [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), but Haskell erases such expensive information as *record label strings* at runtime for very good reasons, and of course the compiler needs to know all the types so they can't be duck-inferred at runtime. In that sense, what you're asking is simply not possible.

Or is it? GHC actually has become pretty good at dependent types. It has been possible for quite some time now to handle non-type-specific labels as *type-level string values*, called [`Symbol`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol)s. And very recently, there has been [work on allowing fields of any record to be accessed *by name*](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields), i.e. much like in Python but all at compile time, with whatever type is contained in the field.

The essential thing is that you need to express the type-level function mapping a record-label and a record-type to a type of contained element. This is expressed by the [`HasField` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html#t:HasField).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, FunctionalDependencies, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import GHC.Records
import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)

data Bar = Bar {barField1 :: Int, barField2 :: String}

data BarError = BarError {barerrField1 :: [String], barerrField2 :: [String]}
 deriving (Show)

type LensOn s a = (a, a -> s)  -- poor man's lens focus

instance HasField "Field2" Bar (LensOn Bar String) where
  getField (Bar i s) = (s, \s' -> Bar i s')

instance HasField "Field2" BarError (LensOn BarError [String]) where
  getField (BarError f₁ f₂) = (f₂, \f₂' -> BarError f₁ f₂')

validateLength :: ∀ (f :: Symbol)
                      . ( HasField f Bar (LensOn Bar String)
                        , HasField f BarError (LensOn BarError [String]) )
    => (Int,Int) -> Bar -> BarError -> BarError
validateLength (mn,mx) record errRecord
    = let len = length . fst $ getField @f record
      in if len < mn || len > mx
          then case getField @f errRecord of
                 (oldRec, setRec) -> setRec $ "incorrect length" : oldRec
          else errRecord

main :: IO ()
main = let x = Bar 10 "hello there"
           xErr = BarError [] []
       in print $ validateLength @"Field2" (3,10) x xErr
```

Tested with GHC-8.3.20170711, probably doesnt' work with significantly older versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a value passed as an argument to operate at two different types, you'll need `Rank2Types` (or the equivalent `RankNTypes`) extension.

Then, since rank-2 or higher types are never inferred in GHC, you'll need to write the type signature explicitly.

Our first pass might look something like: `IsString a => (Int, Int) -> (forall s a. Lens' s a) -> Bar -> BarError -> BarError`  But, that's *way* too general for that second argument, so general I tend to doubt a non-bottom value of that type exists.  We certainly can't pass `field1` or `field2` there.

Since we want to pass `field1` or `field2` we need something that unifies their types: `HasField1 s a => Lens' s a` and `HasField2 s a => Lens' s a`.  Unfortunately, since `HasField1` and `HasField2` do not share (or have) any super classes, the only type that unifies these the the type given in the last paragraph.

Note that even if `HasField1` and `HasField2` shared a super class, we still wouldn't be done.  Your implementation also requires that the field in `Bar` be a `Foldable` and that the field in `BarError` be a list of `IsString`.  Expressing those constraints is possible, but not exactly user-friendly.